# Sass: @each loop within @mixin

Tags: css, sass

Apologies for the amount of Sass here(lol). My context is ive got a map of the original element padding, and I have a variant of that element. The size of the variant wants to be dependant on the original element size but as multiple of it that should be able to be called individually like a mixin variable. That way theres only one variable to change to keep uniform elements of both original and variant elements, but you can also modify all the variant elements individually with the multiplier. With that said here is my code

```
    $input-btn-paddings-x: (
    xs: ($input-btn-padding-x * .789),
    sm: ($input-btn-padding-x * .789),
    md: $input-btn-padding-x,
    lg: ($input-btn-padding-x * 1.315),
    xl: ($input-btn-padding-x * 1.763)
); 
   
$quote-btn-paddings: $input-btn-paddings-x;

$quote-btn-paddings-multiplier: 3; //default if no variable provided


@function quote-btn-paddings($width-multiplier: $quote-btn-paddings-multiplier) {
  @each $breakpoint-size, $quote-btn-padding in $quote-btn-paddings {
    $quote-btn-paddings: map-merge($quote-btn-paddings, ($breakpoint-size: $quote-btn-padding * $width-multiplier));
  }
  @return $quote-btn-paddings;
}

@mixin quote-btn($width-multiplier: $quote-btn-paddings-multiplier) {
  @include button-size(map-get($btn-paddings-y, "md"), quote-btn-paddings($width-multiplier), $btn-font-size-lg, $btn-line-height-lg, $btn-border-radius-lg, true);
}
```

While outside of the @function this works perfectly, it returns the multiplied map. However when used  within the function it just returns the original map values as if no @each operation was performed.

Comment: It's not very clear how you want to use this mixin. The problem here is the scope: the variable `$quote-btn-paddings` is only changed inside the each loop but not on global scope. You should either remove the mixin and do the each loop directly or use a function to return the new map.

Comment: That is completely true and in fact i have posted the wrong code in trying to simplify and condense my issue.  I will update the code to reflect more accurately what im trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

@arkellys was correct in his comment.
I had to return the merged map via a function - however I was resetting the value of

```
$quote-btn-paddings: $input-btn-paddings-x;
```

by having it outside the function (i think)

My solution was to move the new map declaration inside the function and then merge it and return the new map that could be called by the mixin;

```
    //quote button
@function quote-btn-paddings($width-multiplier) {
$quote-btn-paddings: $input-btn-paddings-x;
  @each $breakpoint-size, $quote-btn-padding in $quote-btn-paddings {
    $quote-btn-paddings: map-merge($quote-btn-paddings, ($breakpoint-size: $quote-btn-padding * $width-multiplier));
  }
  @return $quote-btn-paddings;
}

//quote button
@mixin quote-btn($width-multiplier: $quote-btn-paddings-multiplier) {
  @include button-size(map-get($btn-paddings-y, "md"), quote-btn-paddings($width-multiplier), $btn-font-size-lg, $btn-line-height-lg, $btn-border-radius-lg, true);
}
```

then call it like so;

```
@include quote-btn(4);
```